# adding a column dynamically and hiding the first column like jquery slider 

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I have a html page with 10 columns but I don't have show all in same page instead I have to show only 4 column moreover I have to render those column on a button click call add column.
What is the best approach to render 1-4 column first ? Fist column render first and on clicking button say add will render 2nd column , than 3rd and fourth. Now when i will load 5th column ...I will have to hide 1st column so that i will accommodate 4 columns but data inside that column will stay ....my limit is to show 4 column at a time and hiding leftmost ....

any helpful javascript or jquery  advice will be appreciated ..thanks!

Comment: what is a column?  are you using `table`, `tr`, `td`?  unfortunately if you are, columns are not really a thing in themselves.  they are just implicit group of `td` (ie - third `td` of each row)

Comment: @jon... Yes, table with tr, td

Comment: this is gonna be tricky.  are you using class attribute yet?  that might be a good way to mark columns

Comment: yes I am using class....its tricky because my page is complex and each td contains dropdown, text etc...i am not worried about the complexity of the page ...currently I am taking care on 4 td which is not a problem but when I have 10 td i have to show only 4 at a time...moreover td will be added on triggering click event..do you have any idea if  jquery plugin take of that kind of stuff...

Answer (score 0):

yes i think this plug-in can solve your problem....through it you can show and hide your column on click of button...just have a look on it...even i have done the same thing on my page...[Data Table](http://datatables.net/)

And here is your Working example....[Show and hide Column Dynamically](http://datatables.net/examples/api/show_hide.html)

Comment: thanks! but that means I have to render my all 10 table td at a same time and instead dynamically add it ....moreover I have to use a another plugin ...